# How to measure startup time and order of Windows services on boot?

Tags: windows, performance, service

I am not asking how to measure server startup time here.   I am wondering if anyone knows of a tool that can measure and show a graph of the startup time and order of all the windows services during system startup.

I saw a software program shown on my local Portland news last week that does this but I am unable to remember what it was called or anything else about it.  All I remember is that it was a "tech" news story to help computer users with their computers.

So, I know the software exists and I am trying to find it.

Comment: not sure of the specific name but goto microsoft.com/sysinternals I'm pretty sure there is an app for that!  And is that portland,or

Comment: Any software meant for the average computer user, reported about on my local news station, is not going on any computer of mine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this for a Server or Client machine? [Soluto](https://www.soluto.com/boot-time) gives you bootup information. I wouldn't put it on a server as yet (is Beta).

Comment: yep, thats IT!  you are the winner.  Thanks very much!

Comment: I'd be curious as to what info is being sent back to soluto!

Answer (score 2):

No idea. Have you tried contacting the news station or checking their site? Lots of news orgs put their content online, and even if they don't have it there, they'll have contact info for the reporters on the the different beats - their Technology staffers should be listed and you could call or send an email.

Let us know what it was.

/edit - Using the almighty Google for 'windows services start time graph' the first hit is an article that at the end, mentions BootVis[link text](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BootVis). Does that ring a bell?

Comment: I don't think thats it.  Also, Google News search doesn't show any results for "Bootvis" and so that one hasn't been on any news lately (presumably).

Comment: Did you try it? Do the screenshots look like what you saw? Did you contact the news org or at least check their site?

Comment: So the application you saw did graphs of startup times (at system startup) of services, drivers etc?  Procmon lists the start time (at system startup) and duration for each of these it just doesn't natively do the graphs.

Answer (score 1):

I'm concurring with mfinni. What you're probably looking for is BootVis.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're looking for :

http://www.greatis.com/utilities/bootlogxp/

It's only supported on XP and 2003.

Comment: Great non-free alternative, but Soluto, being free, made more sense to me.

Answer (score -1):

here ya go

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx

Comment: Tony - that most assuredly does not do what the OP asked for.

Comment: well it doesn't do the pretty graphs but it will monitor startup processes.